# cURL is being uninstalled on its own on Ubuntu

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, curl

I am running a web server in Ubuntu 16, a typical LAMP so to speak. I need curl-php to test my development scripts in the console instead of having them exposed on the web.

The problem is that although I am installing curl-php by using apt, the package is being uninstalled after a couple of hours and this is happening every day for a reason I can't understand.

I verified the removal of curl-php and any other auto-magically removed packages by using the following command:

```
root@specialserver:~# cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep "\ remove\ "
2019-12-01 16:35:08 remove libcurl3:amd64 7.58.0-2ubuntu2 <none>
2019-12-02 00:50:38 remove curl:amd64 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.8 <none>
2019-12-02 00:50:38 remove php-curl:all 1:7.2+60ubuntu1 <none>
2019-12-02 00:50:38 remove php7.2-curl:amd64 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 <none>
2019-12-02 00:50:38 remove libcurl4:amd64 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.8 <none>
2019-12-02 21:47:13 remove libcurl3:amd64 7.58.0-2ubuntu2 <none>
```

Comment: What's the active version of php on your server 7.2? Also, is it on a VPS server or on your own machine?

Comment: @MihailMinkov it is a dedicated server, I have full root access and the PHP version is 7.2 yes..

Comment: I suppose you installed it using `apt install curl php php-curl`? Do you have any cronjobs you might not be aware of?

Comment: @MihailMinkov I do, actually, but none of them is ever touching the packages. My cronjobs are simply running some PHP and Python scripts written by me... And yes, I installed php-curl with apt install.

Comment: Maybe try to temporarily disable any apt-related tools like "update-manager" or "unattended-upgrades". If the uninstall happens always at the same time, set up a cronjob for that time, regularly dumping the process list to a file. Maybe there's a package (e.g. from a PPA) that conflicts with your curl version, and another curl version is installed?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this is an official Bug for Ubuntu 18 Bionic, where libcurl3 and libcurl4 cannot co-exist.